# Z-index issue - what I miss?

Tags: html, css

This is [the website](https://terramare.com.ua/product/bavarian-pizza/), I didn't create it, I have some tasks, and with that one I need some help. NO - I wouldn't use CODEPEN or something, the website is very big, and 1000% I will miss something, so better to use the inspector F12

There's the logo. The logo has an :after-element, which makes the triangle and drop-shadow effect.
It also makes the area, that doesn't allow to click other elements which are under that area. When border is transparent, it's hard to see, but if to make it red in code inspector, it's visible
[image]

I tried to change positions of logo itself and the :after element - to make logo relative and :after - absolute, and then I gave z-index -999 to :after, it didn't help. All was in the code-inspector.

```
#header.lafka-has-header-top #logo {
    top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
div#header div#header_top div#logo:after {
    content: ''!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    border: 100px solid red !important;
    border-top: 30px solid #ffffff !important;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

[image: after]
[image: logo]

The content under logo already has z-index 100; so I don't have ideas what else can help, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div#header div#header_top div#logo:after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks. helped for desktop version, on mobile is still some issue, on the breadcrumbs middle

Comment: It will also work on mobile. Maybe you need to clear the cache.

Comment: I try - the breadcrumbs can't be clicked, unfortunately

Comment: Works, checked.  Try in the incognito tab.

Comment: checked on mozilla - it works. maybe chrome is cached, I cleared the history though

Comment: Works in chrome also.